# Better way to check for URL in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, pattern-matching

Is there a better way or elegance to do this? I've been using this code to check the similar url in database base on the pattern provide.

```
    $menu_selected = '';
$uri_array = explode('/','commodity/statement/flour/factory/');
    $menus = array(
        'commodity/search/flour/factory/index',
        'commodity/statement/sugar/branch/index'
    );

    $pattern_parts = explode('/', '=/*/=/=/*');

foreach ($menus as $menu) {
    $url_parts = explode('/',$menu);

    if( count($pattern_parts) == count($url_parts) ){

        #[i] Trim down for wildcard pattern
        foreach($pattern_parts as $i => $part ){
            if( $part == '*' ) {
                unset($pattern_parts[$i]);
                unset($url_parts[$i]);
                unset($uri_array[$i]);
            }
        }

        #[i] Join array and compare
        if( join('/', $uri_array) == join('/', $url_parts) ) {
            // Found and return the selected
            $menu_selected = $menu; 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but please stop using the alias and just use `implode()`.

Comment: This is an answer somewhat: Why don't you use a regex pattern to match records in the database?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect opportunity to start learning in that case,

Comment: Correct: If you want a better way, learn regex.

Comment: Haha, sure. Any good tutorial?

Comment: You can play with this for the main time http://codepad.viper-7.com/WmH6yf